# Bootstrap 3 fix container width to media breakpoints

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass, media, breakpoints

How can I fix width of the container to be equal to media break points?  Twiter.com does something similar to this.  The layout is pretty constant until the user resizes the window to a media breakpoint.  Then the layout is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic idea would be:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container"> <!-- standard Bootstrap div ->
 <div class="content-wrap">
  <!-- page content here -->
 </div> <!-- end content-wrap -->  
</div> <!-- end container -->
```

**CSS**

```
@media (min-width: Xpx) {
 .content-wrap{
  width:Xpx
  margin:0 auto;
 }
}
```

You would place the container-wrap element inside your Bootstrap scaffold.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's pseduo code, yes?  I think I just figured it out.

Comment: yes @honkskillet, pseudo code. I'm picturing your CSS sets some basic site-wide defaults first, then you have multiple blocks of this CSS media code for each of your breakpoints. To get CSS cascading to work for you, start with the narrowest viewport first and then work up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have which seems to work.

```
/*==========  FIX WIDTH AT MEDIA BREAKPOINTS ==========*/
/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width :1200px) {
  .media-container{
    width: 1200px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width :1200px) {
  .media-container{
    width: 992px;
  }
}
/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
  .media-container{
    width: 768px;
  }
}
/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
  .media-container{
    width: 480px;
  }
}
/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {
  .media-container{
    width: 320px;
  }
}
/* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
  .media-container{
    width: 320px;  
  }
}
.media-container{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Then my html body looks something like this (I don't want my footer or header to be limited by the constraints).

```
<div class="myHeader"><!-- header markup --></div>
<div class="media-container">
  <!-- my page contents -->
</div>
<div class="myFooter"><!-- footer markup --></div>
```

---

<s>For all you SASS-holes out there, here is a nearly ***indecipherable*** SASS solution...</s>

```
$index-list:          1 2 3 4 5 6;
$min-max-list:        min max max max max max;   //X
$min-max-width-list:  1200 1200 992 768 480 320; //Y
$width-list:          1200 992 768 480 320 320;  //Z
@each $i in $index-list {
  @media only screen and (#{nth($min-max-list,$i)}-width : #{nth($min-max-width-list,$i)}px ) {
    .media-container{
      width: #{nth($width-list,$i)}px;
      margin: 0 auto; 
    }
  }
}
// Produces content of form
// @media only screen and (X-width : Ypx) {
//   .media-container{
//     width: Zpx;  
//   }
// }
```

---

Much more concise, readable SASS version here.

```
// List of media 'breakpoints'
$px-list:             320 480 768 992 1200; //X
@each $px in $px-list {
  @media only screen and (min-width : #{$px}px ) {
    .media-container{
      width: #{$px}px;
      margin: 0 auto; 
    }
  }
}
// Produces content of form
// @media only screen and (min-width : Xpx) {
//   .media-container{
//     width: Xpx; 
//     margin: 0 auto; 
//   }
// }
```